# How to create an admin and allow access to admin panel in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, ecmascript-6

I am very new to coding and am writing a personal project using node.js, express, mongoDB, and mongoose. I wrote most of it myself, however I hired someone to help me with the more advanced parts. I have lost contact with him and went back under the hood to create an admin panel I could use to write blog posts and other things. I am trying to write a middleware that only allows myself access to the route. However it is not working.

```
function adminAuth(req, res, next){
      if(req.user.isAdmin){
        return next();
      } else {
        res.redirect("/");
      }
    }
```

I am a bit confused of the syntax he has used to create a user schema and I am not sure how to add this isAdmin key value pair. Any help updating my users with an isAdmin key value would be extremely appreciated, and also helping me finish the middleware as (req.user.isAdmin) is not working! (If I do not provide the necessary code, please excuse my inexperience and tell me what you would like to see).

Here is the Auth route the coder I hired wrote that I am having trouble deciphering how to pass in new data to the user model.

```
const isAdmin = false;

      const passwordHash = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, saltRounds);

      const db = client.db(dbName);
      const col = db.collection('users');
      const user = {
        email, firstName, lastName, password: passwordHash, isAdmin,
      };
```

local strategy

```
module.exports = function localStrategy() {


passport.use(new Strategy(
    {
      usernameField: 'email',
      passwordField: 'password',
      passReqToCallback: true
    }, (req, email, password, done) => {
      const url = process.env.MONGOLAB_URI;
      const dbName = 'giftgrab';

      (async function addUser() {
        let client;
    try {
      client = await MongoClient.connect(url);

      const db = client.db(dbName);
      const col = db.collection('users');

      const user = await col.findOne({ email });
      debug('Found user by email');
      debug(user);
      if (!user) {
        req.flash('error', 'The username or password is wrong');
        done(null, false);
      } else {
        const match = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);

        if (match) {
          done(null, user);
        } else {
          req.flash('error', 'The username or password is wrong');
          // we pass null because it did not error, just failed
          done(null, false);
        }
      }
    } catch (e) {
      debug(e.stack);
    }

    client.close();
  }());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Here is the Auth route the coder I hired wrote that I am having trouble deciphering how to pass in new data to the user model.

```
// add logic to check if the user is admin
const isAdmin = false;

// user data collected here. If you want to add an "isAdmin" property, this is the right place
const user = {
  email, firstName, lastName, password: passwordHash, isAdmin,
};

// checking if the user already exists
const check = await col.findOne({ email });

if (check) {
  req.flash('error', 'The user with this email already exists');
  res.redirect('back');
} else {
  // the user does not exist, insert a new one and authenticate
  const results = await col.insertOne(user);

  req.login(results.ops[0], () => {
    res.redirect('/');
  });
}
```

This is what related to adding the isAdmin property. In order to use req.user and req.isAuthenticated() you are going to need [Passport.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport). The user data stored in you session (req.user) is defined by your passport strategy so if you want to use the isAdmin property this way, you are going to need to set it there.

Comment: Hey Igor so I tried what you said and now all the users are being created with an isAdmin property so thank you! I am still a bit confused on where to define req.user.isAdmin so my middleware will work. Should it be defined in local.strategy.js or passport.js you created? I updated the question with my code